# Make a orQueryWithSubqueries work as an AND and not OR

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I've got the following query that makes use of `orQueryWithSubqueries`.

At the moment it works as an `OR` and retrieves everything it finds in both sub-queries.

I would expect it to work as an `AND` and retrieve only the objects both have in common.

Is there a way to achieve that with Parse?

```
var today = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.autoupdatingCurrentCalendar()
calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
var cutOffDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, value: -7, toDate: today, options: NSCalendarOptions(0))

var queryDate = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
queryDate.whereKey("createdAt", greaterThan: cutOffDate!)

var queryPosts = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
queryPosts.whereKey("bellongsToStyle", containedIn: selectedStyles)

var query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([queryPosts, queryDate])
query.orderByDescending("votes")
query.includeKey("createdByUser")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do an `AND` for 2 or more queries you would have to chain the method calls on a single query:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
               .whereKey("createdAt", greaterThan: cutOffDate!)
               .whereKey("bellongsToStyle", containedIn: selectedStyles)
               .orderByDescending("votes")
               .includeKey("createdByUser")
```

FWIW the correct spelling of "bellongsToStyle" would be "belongsToStyle".